# ERROR net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract - Unable to load library 'gs': Native library (linux-x86-64/libgs.so) not found in resource path

Tags: linux, ocr, tesseract

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using the above dependency in maven. 
This is used in java and eclipse.

I am now compiling into a executable jar and it executes without any error in windows, since I have 'Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013' installed in windows.

But now i want to run the executable jar in linux machine. I get the following error:

ERROR net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract - Unable to load library 'gs': Native library (linux-x86-64/libgs.so) not found in resource path ([file:/MedEq/OCR/dme-ocr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar])
Please download, install GPL Ghostscript from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/files
and/or set the appropriate environment variable.
[pool-2-thread-2] ERROR net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract - Could not initialize class org.ghost4j.GhostscriptLibrary
Please download, install GPL Ghostscript from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/files
and/or set the appropriate environment variable.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load library 'gs': Native library (linux-x86-64/libgs.so) not found in resource path ([file:/OCR/dme-ocr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar])
Please download, install GPL Ghostscript from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/files
and/or set the appropriate environment variable.
        at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.PdfUtilities.convertPdf2Tiff(PdfUtilities.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.ImageIOHelper.getIIOImageList(ImageIOHelper.java:343)
        at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:213)
        at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:197)

Comment: which linux distribution and version? Which java version? Which tess4j version?

Comment: @4F2E4A2E Linux version : RedHat Enterprise (Aws ec2 instance)
Java Version : 1.7
Tess4j version : 3.2.1

Installed in RHEL machine,
leptonica-1.75.3
tesseract-ocr-3.02.02
latest GhostScript (Since I did yum install Ghostscript)

Please help me if this is a compatibility issue or something I should fix with Linux machine.

I have bundled jar with tess4j which runs in windows, but in Linux machine, I am unable to run the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Install GhostScript on Linux, then you'd be good.

`sudo apt-get install ghostscript`

Comment: I did this. Still I get this error. should I check for specific library paths for the .so files?

Comment: You may need to create a softlink `libgs.so` to the actual GS `.so` file.

Comment: #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9b2724611a, pid=29800, tid=140304365639424
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgs.so+0x39f11a]  errwrite+0xa
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

Comment: I get the above error. I created the softlink. I am runnning in a multi threaded environment. Java Version 1.7